# gawk is treating NF and custom variables differently even though they have the same value

Tags: awk, csv

I have the below awk script where I'm using the length of the array passed, as a variable.

```
BEGIN {
    FPAT = "([^,]*)|(\"[^\"]*\")"
    len=split(_arr,arr," ")
}

{
    for(i=1;i<=len;i++){
        print("i: " i " value i: " $i)
    }
}
```

For the below command

```
gawk -F ',' -v _arr="(1 2 3)" -f stackOverflow.awk example2.csv
```

and the below input

```
,112,41/12/2023
new,23,21/10/2022
,421,11/01/12
abce,421,11/14/12
```

The output I get is :

```
i: 1 value i: 
i: 2 value i: 
i: 3 value i: 
i: 1 value i: new
i: 2 value i: 23
i: 3 value i: 21/10/2022
i: 1 value i: 
i: 2 value i: 
i: 3 value i: 
i: 1 value i: abce
i: 2 value i: 421
i: 3 value i: 11/14/12
```

But if I use NF instead of len like below

```
BEGIN {
    FPAT = "([^,]*)|(\"[^\"]*\")"
    len=split(_arr,arr," ")
}

{
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
        print("i: " i " value i: " $i)
    }
}
```

I get my desired output.

```
i: 1 value i: 
i: 2 value i: 112
i: 3 value i: 41/12/2023
i: 1 value i: new
i: 2 value i: 23
i: 3 value i: 21/10/2022
i: 1 value i: 
i: 2 value i: 421
i: 3 value i: 11/01/12
i: 1 value i: abce
i: 2 value i: 421
i: 3 value i: 11/14/12
```

I'm using

```
GNU Awk 4.2.1, API: 2.0 (GNU MPFR 4.0.2, GNU MP 6.1.2)
Copyright (C) 1989, 1991-2018 Free Software Foundation.
```

and I prefer to use the same version

Comment: Possibly this? https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/gawk.git/commit/?id=df52ba3de4c18482e2d6f81b94f3e9cd6c83aa7a

Comment: Read also [`FIELDWIDTHS`, `FPAT` and `FS`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/User_002dmodified.html) behavior when setting one/two or all three of them.

Answer (score 4):

You're mixing several different ways to split strings here - you're defining `FPAT` in the `BEGIN` section with `FPAT = "([^,]*)|(\"[^\"]*\")"` but you're also defining `FS` on the command line with `-F ','` and then you're calling split with a field separator of `" "` with `split(_arr,arr," ")` which tells it to ignore both `FS` and `FPAT`.

Then you're trying to use `NF` which IS set based on either `FS` or `FPAT`, whichever was defined last in your code (which I believe would be taken to be `FPAT` given your code but don't do that) but then for some reason you expect it to be the same as `len` which is the output of a totally unrelated `split()` using a hard-coded `" "` as the field separator.

Also, FS and FPAT are splitting the lines of your input file while `split(_arr,...," ")` is splitting the contents of the string `_arr` you passed as a variable - 2 totally unrelated things.

You're also passing in a string with `_arr="(1 2 3)"` but calling it an array and then when you split it into an actual array you'll have `(1` and `2` and `3)` (with the parens in those parts) but you're not using any of those values in your script.

So it's obvious why your code behaves as it does (your 3 different definitions of field separators and then `len` set by `split(_arr,...," ")` splitting the contents of `_arr` vs `NF` set by `FS` or `FPAT` splitting the contents of `$0`) but it's not clear what you're trying to do or we could help you do whatever that is the right way.

Having said all of that - there are FPAT bugs in older versions of gawk, see the following thread for a description of one such problem and a workaround:

- https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-gawk/2017-04/msg00000.html

and a couple more:

- https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-gawk/2015-09/msg00034.html
- https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-gawk/2019-11/msg00000.html

and get a newer version of gawk than 5.0.1 (the current version is 5.2.1).

Comment: At least the last two linked posts mention that even referring to `NF` works as some sort of a "fix" for some of the `FPAT` bugs, and that seems to be the crux of the matter here, as far as the difference between the two scripts is concerned anyway. If I read the docs right, `FS` should be ignored if `FPAT` is set, and the odd way `len` is set from an unrelated value shouldn't affect the output since the loop runs from 1 to 3 in both cases on all input lines. I wonder if the result would be the same with `-F` and `_arr` dropped, and `len` set as just `len=3`.

Comment: @ilkkachu - awk uses whichever of FS or FPAT was set more recently, in this case I expect that'd be FPAT even though both are set before the first file is opened.